# R sound vs L sound

Tags: pronunciation

First, I'd like to mention that I've seen [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11000/how-is-determined-whether-a-sound-should-be-romanized-into-an-l-versus-an-r), which is related but doesn't quite seem to be a duplicate.

I've covered some Hiragana lessons and it seems there is no L in Japanese. The Japanese R seems to be a bit closer to L than the English R, but still, the Japanese accent stereotype doesn't seem to be far fetched. For example, the nice lady in [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rGrBHiuPlT0)(at the very beginning) says:

> Konnichiwa, let's start(u) tuday's reson.

But on the other hand, [when she speaks about numbers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bOUqVC4XkOY)(0:38), she pronounces the number 6 with a clear L sound: /lok(u)/, although [the romaji spelling seems to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_numerals) *roku*

From the linked question I understood that the difference between L and R sounds in Japanese is not clearcut. My question is: what exactly does "not clearcut" mean? Does it mean that certain words are pronounced with r (such as *suru*) and others with l (such as *roku*)? Or is it a dialect thing? Or is it personal preference, i.e. some people from the same region will say /rok(u)/ while others will say /lok(u)/?

I actually  have a similar question about /dz/ and /j/ sounds (in particular, I can't understand how is 10 supposed to be pronounced). If the answer is similar, please mention that, otherwise I'll ask a separate question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you pronounce the Japanese "r"?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1199/how-do-you-pronounce-the-japanese-r)

Comment: @Ataraxia I don't think that it does.  It only describes the intervocalic allophone of /r/, not the utterance-initial /r/, which I think is what the OP is hearing in /roku/.  It also doesn't mention the "unspecified for laterality" aspect, which could also explain the discrepancy in what the OP is hearing.

Comment: Remember that we shouldn't close questions as duplicates just because they're about the same subject.  We should only close as duplicates *if the answers on the other question answer this question as well*, and in this case, I don't think they do.  (This is different from how we used to use "close as duplicate"; for more information, please see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166707/changes-to-close-as-duplicate-part-deux) on MSO.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The sound called /r/ in Japanese is not quite the same sound as the L or R sounds of English.  And as you've correctly observed, there's more than one way to pronounce /r/ in Japanese.  There are a couple technical terms from linguistics that might help:

- /r/ is considered a ***phoneme***.  That means it's considered a single sound, even if it's technically pronounced a little bit differently sometimes.
- The individual pronunciations are called ***allophones***.

With the /r/ sound, there are two main allophones to consider.  (The following is based on *The Sounds of Japanese* by Timothy Vance, page 89):

1. The first one is the one described in the answer istrasci links to; it's called an [***apico-alveolar tap***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_tap), and it's written with the IPA symbol [ɾ].  This sound involves quickly tapping the tongue on the roof of the mouth, specifically on the [***alveolar ridge***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_ridge) (the ridge located behind the teeth).  The ***apico-*** part of the name means that you use specifically the tip of your tongue, not the blade.
2. The second one is what Timothy Vance refers to as a ***non-tap allophone***.  In this version of /r/, the tongue is *already resting on the roof of the mouth*, so all you do is pull your tongue off instead of tapping.  And this is the allophone you heard in *roku*.  (For whatever reason, Vance chooses not to give this allophone a separate symbol, so I'll refer to it by name instead.)

This ***non-tap allophone*** occurs when it's the first sound you say (called ***utterance-initial position***).  And that's why you heard it in *roku*, because she wasn't saying anything before she started to say the /r/ sound.  The non-tap allophone also occurs ***immediately after an /N/ sound***, as in the words *benri* or *jinrui*.

The ***tap allophone*** occurs in any other position, which in Japanese amounts to ***intervocalic position*** (meaning between vowel sounds).

---

Understanding the two allophones described above is important, but there's also some personal variation in exactly how the /r/ sound is pronounced.  It varies from speaker to speaker, and it may vary a bit even for a single speaker.  Although I described a [***central tap***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_tap) above, which is written [ɾ], the Japanese /r/ isn't specifically central.  It can instead be a [***lateral tap***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alveolar_lateral_flap), which is written [ɺ].  I think it's possible that you may perceive the lateral tap as sounding more like an English L sound.

Unfortunately, I've been unable to find any references that describe exactly when [ɾ] is used and when [ɺ] is used.  They're described as being in [***free variation***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variation) in Japanese, which means that speakers can use either central or lateral versions of /r/ in any context without it being considered strange or in error.  However, it's often true that sounds described as being in "free variation" are [***not actually selected at random***](http://dialectblog.com/2011/10/29/free-variation-isnt-so-free/), and I suspect this may be true of Japanese as well.

It's possible that these or other variations in the Japanese /r/ may lead you to think that sometimes it sounds more like L, and sometimes it sounds more like R.  That's fine, of course, but it's important that you realize all these sounds are simply ***one phoneme*** in Japanese.  That is, no matter how you pronounce /r/, it's still mentally /r/ to a native speaker of Japanese.  And the more you study Japanese, the more you're likely to feel the same way.

In my opinion, you should focus on learning when to use the tap allophone, and when to use the non-tap allophone.  I wouldn't worry as much about the other sorts of variation.  If you do that, then I think the idea of an L versus R contrast in Japanese will disappear for you, and before long, it'll just be /r/ to you, too.

Comment: From my experience, the lateral version is used in the non-tap variant **except** after the moraic nasal /N/; in all other cases the central version is used. The lateral version is also used when talking very slowly, such as in a slow song, a large part of the /r/'s could be lateral rather than central. Then again, I have not much experience in Japanese except watching NHK every now and then.

Comment: Fantastic answer. I had always wondered about what I was suppose to do with /nr/, and have been doing some complicated maneuver which is impossible in fast speech. Not tapping actually sounds fine; I've no idea why I haven't been doing that this whole time!

Comment: One thing I noticed from living near Tokyo (other regions may vary) but I noticed that when the /r/ came at the start of a word it tended to have an "L" like character to it, but when it was inside a word, it tended to have more of an "R" character to it. I often hear らーめん pronounced like "laamen" but something like バラ pronounced like the romaji "bara". If I said "bala" that sounds totally wrong, but "laamen" doesn't sound so bad.

Comment: Do you know why the Japanese /r/ was transcribed as R rather than L? As native English speaker (which I'm not) I would have chosen L, I think, because to my ear the standard English R (Scottish pronunciation aside) is much further from the Japanese /r/ than the English L...

Comment: @Earthling Hepburn wrote "*r* in *ra,ri,ru,re,ro* has the sound of English, *r*; but in *ri*, it is pronounced more like *d*. But this is not invariable as many natives give it the common *r* sound." (From *A Japanese and English Dictionary: with an English and Japanese Index*, page ix.)  To me, this explanation sounds like a bunch of nonsense, but that's what he wrote :-)

Comment: @Earthling To me, the non-tap allophone sounds closer to L, and the tap allophone sounds closer to R.  But neither sounds much like my English L or R sounds.  (I should note that, in my dialect, the L sound doesn't involve touching my tongue to the roof of my mouth.)  The closest modern American English comes to the tap allophone is the [flapped /t/ or /d/ sounds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flapping) in words like *writer* or *rider*, but that sounds different to me too, perhaps because the tongue touches in a slightly different position, or perhaps because it can't be [ɺ].

Comment: @Earthling it sounds close to Spanish/Portugese R, and I think that was why 'r' was chosen. In English, l or d would be a better choice.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, let's make a distinction between romaji (which only has r) and actual pronunciation, which alternates between l and r.

The truth is that l and r are in free distribution in Japanese, ie. both sounds are possible surface realizations of the same underlying sound (similar to how t in top and in stop are different in English but are considered to be the same sound by native speakers).

In general, the sound is a flapped r, but you will find an increasing rate of occurrence of l: 1) in woman, 2) in slower speech, 3) at the beginning of words. If dialectal or regional considerations come into play, I haven't heard or noticed anything to that effect.